# Formatting negative numbers with math minus (U+2212) instead of hyphen-minus (U+002D)

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to format negative numbers as strings where the minus sign has the same font width of plus sign. With

```
>>> '{}'.format(-2)
'-2'
```

the minus sign you get in the resulting string is the character `u'\u002d'` (I use [this website](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) to check character codes), which in many fonts is much narrower and even lower than plus sign.

Instead I would like the minus sign to be represented by the character `u'\u2212'`, which is the mathematical minus sign and has the same width and vertical alignment of plus sign in all fonts (at least the ones I checked and I'll ever need).

Is there a way to change the behavior of a Python environment so that, when formatting negative numbers, math minus sign (U+2212) is used instead of hyphen-minus (U+002D)?

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for my needs:

In:

```
negative = u'\u2212'
output = f"{negative}{abs(-2)}"
print(output)
print('vs.')
print(-2)
```

Out:
−2 vs. -2

Edit: formatting

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a low level way (a module, a Python option) to obtain that automatically, without changing standard formatting code.